# Converting current function for future elements

Tags: jquery, ajaxify

Trying to make this (works for first page):

```
$(".text").not(".active a").hover(function(){
```

apply to ajaxify loaded elements.

Tried:

```
 $(document).on("hover",".text:not(.active a)",function(){
```

Doesn't work.

Am I missing something?

**EDIT**
Let me add that the structure is as follows:

```
 <ul id="static-bar" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <li class="active">
     <div data-hoverLeft="home" class="active-tail-top tail-and-point"></div>
     <div data-hoverLeft="home" class="active-tail-bottom tail-and-point"></div>
     <a id="home" class="text" href="index.html">HOME</a>
     <div data-hoverRight="home" class="active-point-top tail-and-point"></div>
     <div data-hoverRight="home" class="active-point-bottom tail-and-point"></div>
   </li>
   <li>
     <div data-hoverLeft="whatWeDo" class="tail-top-gray tail-and-point"></div>
     <div data-hoverLeft="whatWeDo" class="tail-bottom-gray tail-and-point"></div>
     <a id="whatWeDo" class="text" href="what-we-do.html">WHAT WE DO</a>
     <div data-hoverRight="whatWeDo" class="point-top-gray tail-and-point"></div>
     <div data-hoverRight="whatWeDo" class="point-bottom-gray tail-and-point"></div
   </li>
 </ul>
```

The important things to note are that I apply the active class when I'm on that particular page.  Regardless, each link gets a tail and point using some CSS border trickery, and the border color of the sibling `div`s changes when you hover over the `a` tag.  This hover effect doesn't work past the first page when I use the `$.hover()` method, and not at all when I use `$.on()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
$(document).on("hover",".text:not(.active) a",function(){
```

---

Based on your added HTML markup, you need to select any anchor with class `text` which is staying inside a `<li>` that not has class `active`:

```
$(document).on("mouseover","li:not(.active) a.text",function(){
    $(this).addClass('red');
}).on('mouseout', "li:not(.active) a.text",function(){
    $(this).removeClass('red');
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R4nys/)**

Comment: Doesn't work, I added some extra markup above to illustrate the layout I'm working with.  This selects for an anchor that is a child of the `.text` class, when I want to select for the `.text` class that isn't a child of the `.active` class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on("mouseover","li:not(.active) a.text",function(){
  // your code goes here
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work, I added some extra markup above to illustrate the layout I'm working with.  This selects for an anchor that is a child of the `.text` class, when I want to select for the `.text` class that isn't a child of the `.active` class.